# schedule app: how to save editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm beginner developer and I am trying to make a **schedule app** with **tabbed activity** and I want each tab to be a day and in each day/tab there are a couple of plain texts with hints and user can fill the plain text, but the problem is if I fill the plain text with text then close the app the text will disappear and I have to refill the plain text again.

**How can I save the text inside of the plain text and make it appear when I open the app**

please help

Answer (score 2):

You can use [shared-preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

in `onStop`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), editText.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

and in `onResume`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
editText.setText(sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue));
```

do this for every textView you have.